# Method to Cancel Email Alerts, or at least see which ones are scheduled

Tags: email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

We have an email alert that is setup using a Time-Based Workflow rule.

The time-based part is setup on Opportunity creation.

There are rare instances when we have to Cancel the Opportunity (closed - lost), and in my understanding of time-based workflow rules, the email alert will still fire because it was setup on creation only.

There isn't a better way that I can setup the assignment of the Email Alert. At least not that I've thought of yet given the criteria.

1) Ideally it would be great if there was some query I could run that would identify all scheduled email alerts, and then allow me to delete it from the queue.  Does that exist?

2) If that's not possible, is there a place I can go to at least just see what is still in the queue?

Comment: its something managed by Salesforce engine and you cannot alter or query it and handle.

Comment: query it where?

Comment: Setup | Monitoring | Time-based workflows will show you pending workflow actions

Comment: That helps. I didn't know that existed. I wish it would take me directly to the alerts and not just the whole rule - because there are more scheduled things that should still fire.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that adding a condition in your Workflow **only** to execute the Time-based Workflow if

`Status != 'Closed - Lost'`

would be the easiest solution.